# read/write/move raw file using Azure Functions with python

Tags: python-3.x, azure-functions

can any one help below task how can i do.

need to read/write/move raw file into azure, by using of azure data factory V2 and azure function with python.

i search all but i could not find the steps.

Guide me
advance thanks.

Comment: Can you explain a little more please. where does the file seat at the begining ? Is data factory the destination ? Need more clarification and explanation if you want some help

Comment: How are you planning on triggering your function executions? Also, note that Python is an experimental language on Functions V1.

Comment: on premise file server to--> integration run time(gateway)--->daily triggered raw file copy ADF V2---->data lake raw file---->daily trigger ADV V2--->Azure function /python

Answer (score 0):

**Triggering your Function**
Azure functions needs some notion of when to [trigger](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-triggers-bindings) your code. There is no current built in trigger for Azure Data Factory, but this [source](http://visualbi.com/blogs/azure/execute-azure-functions-azure-data-factory/) has some ways of handling this indirectly.

*Method 1:*

Direct your file to some intermediate source that Azure Functions does have a trigger for, like Azure Blob Storage, or some exposed server that the External File Trigger can bind from. This adds an extra step in the layer, and might not be ideal.

*Method 2:*

Set up an HTTP Trigger, and use the URL provided by that function as a Web Linked Service or HTTP Data Source.

**Using Python**

For examples of Python in Azure Functions, see this [repo](https://github.com/yokawasa/azure-functions-python-samples). Note that this language is experimental for Azure Functions, and may change in the future.

**Manipulating Files in Azure**

As for the move/write/read operations of files into Azure, once the function itself is triggered, you can use one of the Azure Functions [output bindings](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-triggers-bindings) to perform operations on various data sources within Azure.